# Cannot load socket.io.js with apache proxy setup

Tags: apache, node.js, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I feel like this question might be a duplicate but from all similar threads I have checked still wasn't able to find a answer.

I have vhost setup to proxy /node/ request to NodeJS/Socket.IO server.

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass /node http://192.168.2.151:1337/
ProxyPassReverse /node http://192.168.2.151:1337/
```

This setup successfully serves everything from Apache, expect requests: http://domain.com/node/
Everything works fine when it comes to NodeJS.

I just can't get this line:

```
<script src="/node/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

to load socket.io.js, it always spits out what NodeJS server has to say.

The setup:

index.html is served by Apache. http://domain.com/index.html
index.html is simple HTML with script tag for loading socket.io.js (like I wrote above).
When I request http://domain.com/index.html script src is loaded but the content is NodeJS servers response instead of socket.io.js.

I have 'npm install socket.io' in the directory where NodeJS server is running from.

I have tried to serve index.html with NodeJS as well, regardless - socket.io.js content is still NodeJS responce.

Did anyone had this problem? Or could link me to an answer? :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question and all of the answers at serverfault: [Configuring Apache2 to proxy WebSocket?](https://serverfault.com/questions/290121/configuring-apache2-to-proxy-websocket%5D).

The problem is that `mod_proxy` doesn't support WebSockets and just makes it an HTTP request. You could use a different port and avoid proxying, switch to Nginx, try haproxy or **use various other Apache module alternatives.** For instance, `mod_proxy_wstunnel` is basically `mod_proxy` with WebSockets support. See the serverfault link above for details on all of the solutions.